# This page isn't working redirected you too many times

Tags: laravel, facebook, laravel-5, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to use Socialite library in Laravel 5 and Facebook API to create a "login with Facebook" feature.  I followed all of the steps in the tutorial and created an app on Facebook developers, but when I click on the login button, it crashes with the error "This page isn't working redirected you too many times."  Below is my callback code. Why isn't this working?

```
public function handleFacebookCallback()
{
    try {
        $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
        $create['name'] = $user->getName();
        $create['email'] = $user->getEmail();
        $create['facebook_id'] = $user->getId();

        $userModel = new User;
        $createdUser = $userModel->addNew($create);
        Auth::loginUsingId($createdUser->id);

        return redirect()->route('home');

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        dd($e);
        return redirect('auth/facebook');

    }
}
```

Comment: Share `addNew` function?

Comment: please show us your full route with middleware

Comment: I think you used wrong syntax for redirection, try this: `return redirect()->to('/home');`

Comment: I did this because its 1:00am and I spent 2.5 hours Googling and basically all of the answers on the Internet for "This page isn't working. redirected you too many times" are "clear your cookies" and "use a different browser" which are completely off base.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error message because the code in try block is failing and executing the catch block which is redirecting the request back to the server which is sending it back to the browser over and over.  Die and dumping (dd) the exception reveals this error message:

```
General error: 1364 Field 'password' doesn't have a default value
```

The "create new user" function isn't working because the database is sending back a fatal error.  The database is dying because there is no value for the password in the insert and the table requires it.  Which makes sense when you think about it because the user is creating an account via Facebook and not creating a user ID and password.

Making the password column in the user table able to be null fixes this "[x] redirected you too many times" error.